# How do I get photo albums to sync via iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos.app

I seem to remember photo albums that I created/edited on my iphone syncing via icloud with iphoto and my ipad. After a full restore and update, I can no longere make this work. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

iCloud only synchronizes photos in your 'Camera Roll' through Photo Stream.
iCloud doesn't synchronize photo albums.

It is possible to synchronize photo albums in iPhoto with your iOS device, but for that you need to sync your iOS device with iTunes on your Mac.

Connect your iOS device with your Mac > click on your device in the left column in iTunes > click the 'Photo' tab > there you can select which photo albums you want to sync with your iOS device.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for the clarification. I wonder where I got my wires crossed. However, what I really want is for albums that I create and organize on my iphone to show up in iPhoto, which doesn't seem to happen no matter what I do.

Comment: I've already looked into that because it's something I want too, but unfortunately that's not (yet?) possible.

Comment: This is ridiculous. I could not believe this could be true - it's like not being able to see playlists of your music on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make a Photo Stream like you would an album. They don't need to be shared with anyone so that's what I do... and if you decide later that you want to share the Photo Stream with anyone, you can easily do that by editing it. I hope that helps! :-)